# Django, django-allauth and the battlenet provider

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-allauth

First time attempting to use oauth with python django and django-allauth. I can't seem to make logins happen. I can get to the point where you are asked to authorize your site with battlenet, but when you're redirected to the callback url I just get this:

```
{'code': 'unknown', 'provider': 'battlenet', 'exception': ProxyError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='us.battle.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /oauth/token (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',)))",),)}
```

I have created my application in dev.battle.net, I've put the client key and the secret key in my django-allauth app, but I get stuck at this point.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to answer my own question.

I'm using pythonanywhere to host this for now and I was using the free service. Seems there's a white list of urls that you can hit if you're a free user and us.battle.net was not on the list. I registered for a month and after a few minutes my oauth calls work fine.

If anyone else happens to be in my situation, here's the list of sites that pythonanywhere can hit for free accounts.

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/

Answer (score 0):

What kind of proxy are you running? Nginx + Gunicorn? It's trying to hit '/oauth/token' and failing on that. I've just set up a allauth with Battle.net but I didn't see this along the way.

What does your urls.py and settings.py look like?

- You need to have SITE_ID specified in your settings file.
- Ensure your reverse proxy is handling https requests.

Comment: Turns out it was pythonanywhere blocking me as a free user. I appreciate you taking the time to comment.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! :)